# MSSQL Find Matching Columns in tables with no defined relationships

Tags: sql-server

Is there a script out there that will let MSSQL find columns with records that have the same data in multiple tables.

What I want to do is find the primary keys to data tables that we imported from excel spread sheets that were made from another database.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Is the other database local, or remote?  Is it SQL Server as well?  What versions...

Comment: The tables have all been imported into the same database. This is on MSSQL Server 2008.

Comment: You are going to need to provide a ton more information to get help on this one. SQL isn't a magic box that can read your mind, so the answer is very likely no.

Comment: Well would it be possible to iterate through each permutation of 2 column combinations and check each record against each other to see if there are any matching columns between all the tables in the database? It would be slow but I would be able to run this for a few days if i needed to. I want to avoid looking at each column manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to look up the SysObjects and SysColumn system tables, very handy for this sort of thing.

Here's an example that looks through all tables for the integer value 500.  Note that if you want to look for a different type of column you'll need to change the xtype.  It's not a full blown "Compare every column in my database against every other column" example however it should give you the basic idea and hopefully get you started.

Additionally I'm using a memory table for this example.  If your database is large you will want to use a temporary table and a cursor likely.

This returns a single column recordset with the value of "Table - ColumnName = Search Value"

```
-- declare my search table
DECLARE @Columns TABLE (TableName varchar(50), ColumnName varchar(50))
DECLARE @Results TABLE (Results VARCHAR(255))
DECLARE @SearchData INT
SET @SearchData = 500

DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Command VARCHAR(1024)

-- Find all tables with an integer column
Insert INTO @Columns
    Select sysobjects.[Name] as TableName, syscolumns.[Name] as ColumnName 
        from dbo.sysobjects INNER Join dbo.syscolumns ON dbo.sysobjects.id = dbo.syscolumns.id 
        Where sysobjects.xtype = 'U' and syscolumns.xtype = 56 Order By TableName, ColumnName

--Loop!
WHILE NOT (Select TOP 1 TableName from @Columns) IS NULL
    BEGIN
        Select TOP 1 @TableName = TableName, @ColumnName = ColumnName from @Columns

        SET @Command = 'Select ''' + @TableName + ' - ' + @ColumnName + ' = ' + CAST(@SearchData as varchar(32)) + ''' FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' = ' + CAST(@SearchData as VARCHAR(32))
        Insert INTO @Results
            exec(@Command)

        Delete from @Columns where TableName = @TableName AND ColumnName = @ColumnName
    END


-- Export all results
Select * from @Results
```

Comment: Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, Line 12
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Change @Results to DECLARE @Results TABLE (Results VARCHAR(2048)) which should be large enough regardless of your data if still looking for integers.  Additionally if any of your columns or tables have names more than 50 characters long you are going to want to alter those variables as well.